# Which mode describes this modulation scheme

Tags: digital-modes, modes

I have a modulation mode:

- *(to be used for a satellite)*
- *(of a series of AX.25 frames)*
- *(in the 70 cm band)*
- 9.6 kbps
- Ideally BPSK or QPSK modulation
- but could be plain FM

Which I need to describe with an abbreviation from the table of modes recognised by our amateur radio regulator (in South Africa):

[image: Table of mode descriptions]

I suppose the same would apply to all packet radio operation, really.
Which mode fits best?

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of google:

It seems **J2D** describes this mode best.
The ITU says in [this workshop document](https://www.itu.int/en/ITU-R/terrestrial/workshops/RRS-13-Americas/Documents/Systems_ClassofEmissions_RRS13.pdf) that J2D is

> Single-sideband, suppressed carrier with single channel containing quantized or digital information for data transmission

[Wikipedia has a more detailed table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_radio_emissions) from which we could construct new mode names, **G1B** or **G1D**,

- G (phase modulation)
- 1 (single channel containing digital information, no subcarrier)
- B (Electronic telegraphy, intended to be decoded by machine (radioteletype and digital modes))
  or
- D Data transmission, telemetry or telecommand (remote control)

For digital modulation, I'm not sure it's worth separating Phase modulation from Frequency modulation.

Answer (score 1):

You can figure it out yourself using this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_radio_emissions)

Example: `BPSK` or `QPSK` would be `J2B`

[EDIT]

The other answer given is `J2D` or `G1B` / `G1D`, which is specifically for Data, and I must agree that is probably a better type indication.

This is totally dependent on how your protocol is structured, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

In our national frequency plan, sub bands reserved for digital data, including packet radio are marked as dedicated for modes A1D, A2D, F1D, F2D, J2D

A     Amplitude modulation

F     Frequency modulation

J     SSB modulation

1   One channel containing digital information, no subcarrier

2   One channel containing digital information, using a subcarrier

D   Data transmission

Comment: Could you provide a reference?

Comment: I could lot properly format text in comment so i updated answer.